# Handling Subset Branches in GIT

Tags: git, subset, branch

I want to have a branch in GIT which only contains a subset of the repository. I know this is possible because I can create files in **master** which don't appear in another branch, call it **project**. I could also create a **project** branch and then delete the files I don't want to be in that branch

I'll create a worktree to contain **project**.

1. In the **project** worktree, if I make changes, and commit, I'll still have just the **project** files in the worktree, right?
2. I can then merge **project** into **master** and not change **project**, right?
3. Is there a way to merge **master** into **project** and only merge those files which were already in **project**?  In other words, keep the **project** branch as a subset?